# Reporting services custom assembly language translation issue

Tags: c#, reporting-services, embedded-resource

OK here is my scenario  I have a reporting services 2008 report with a custom assembly that is used to translate common phrases into multiple languages. I have recently updated my solution from VS2012 to VS2017 project file and have found when I import the new dll into reporting services the language files are not being picked up.

I have tested the custom assembly in a simple console app and that works fine. The assembly is running .net 3.5 which is the version supported by SQLRS2008, the assembly has the [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] in, all the resx files and folder are showing in the reporting services bin folder and the config file has been updated. Im using report builder 3 to test the report.

I've been on this for days and cant work it out. Its not giving me any error messages just doing the translation in English. There must be someone out there that can help with this.

Comment: Have you tried forcing 32-bit in your compile settings?  Also, is your custom assembly part of server-side or client-side?

Comment: My assembly is part of a server side mvc application the build is set to any CPU. ill change to x86 to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Tried changing to x86 but reporting services rejects it with the error "Could not load file or assembly 'SDSOnlineV3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Comment: Your resource assembly could be using another assembly from your mvc app that you forgot to deploy to the new ssrs bin folder.

Comment: The assembly is using the correct resources, if I test the assembly in a simple console application app and reference the dll in the reporting services folder, it picks up the correct translations.